# Export S3 Bucket To Blob Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, throttling

I'm trying to download, transform and upload an entire S3 bucket to Azure Blob Storage. The task itself, though trivial, became really annoying due to throttling issues. 
The bucket itself is 4.5TB and contains roughly 700,000,000 keys - my first approach was to create a Lambda to handle a batch of 2000 keys at a time and just attack S3. After launching all the lambdas I came across S3 throttling for the first time -

> {
>       "errorMessage": "Please reduce your request rate.",
>       "errorType": "SlowDown"}

At first this was amusing, but eventually it became a blocker on the whole migration process. Transferring the entire bucket with this throttling policy will take me around 2 weeks.
Of course I implemented an exponential retry but in this scale of 100+ lambdas concurrently it has little effect.
Am I missing something? Is there a service I could use to that ? Can I overcome the throttling someway ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe the “transform” part in your question? Is it necessary to download the objects from S3 first?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes. I need to delete certain properties from the files (sanitisation) before uploading them back.

Comment: Understood. If it were simple copying, you could have made use of `Azure Storage Async Blob Copy` feature. I wrote a blog post long time back (when this feature was announced): https://gauravmantri.com/2012/06/15/how-to-copy-a-bucket-from-amazon-s3-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-copy-blob/. You may find it useful.

Comment: This depends on aspects of S3 and of your bucket that are not user-accessible, but you may find that if you randomize your keys -- don't send the requests with the object keys in their natural order -- you may see improved performance.  Anecdotally, `503 Slow Down` may indicate that the bucket is aware of the traffic increase and is attempting to scale up its capacity, so this *may* resolve itself.  Also anecdotally, a request rate of around 800/sec may be an appropriate target rate to try.

Comment: yes, you want to completely randomise your GETs, and the IO load. Throwing more lambdas at it will not help you.